# How to import 3ds max models into C++/Open GL with animations

Tags: c++, opengl, max, 3ds

I'm wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to import 3ds max models into C++ or OpenGL with it's animation?

Comment: search for "3DS"::"fileformat" there are many tutorials how to load 3ds models (*.3ds not *.max !!!) to C++ app and visualize with OpenGL or DX. with source.  It is not that hard to code it for yourself but it is a lot of coding ...

Comment: and also you can try export model to ASCII (very easy to read) ... but i am not sure if animation is there present also

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to export them to FBX file and then write an FBX parser using the fbx sdk. This way you will extract mesh and other data from the file and send to OpenGL via appropriate API calls. Note that OpenGL is a low level graphics API that doesn't understand file formats or animations out of the box. Animations are especially a tricky part to do.

You can also use Assimpn lib to read a lot of 3D files. Though I am not sure if FBX is supported.